# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11)

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, runtime-error

I'm trying to launch my java applet (version java 6) in server webpage but When I run it i have the next error:

```
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at es.inteco.applet.AppletFirmaDNIe.init(AppletFirmaDNIe.java:168)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Excepción: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11)
Ignored exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11)
```

With eclipse, this Applet works fine but when I try it in the server don't work. 
I'm using an unsigned applet (.jar). Can be this, the ploblem??

In my java .policy file I added these lines and still not working

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
permission java.security.AccessControlException;
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission;
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11";
};
```

the same error like with these original .policy file:

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Have anybody idea of the problem and the solution??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign your applet, and latest java security baseline will block any applet signed with an untrusted certificate authority.

If you choose to self-sign the applet, you may need to lower your java security settings in order for your applet to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's recent Java distributions (since roughly last summer) has disabled access to anything in any package that starts with "sun.".

This can be overcome by using *policytool* to add:

permission java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.

to your local java.policy file.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `java.policy` file or use the [policytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/wstep1.html):

```
grant {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun "com.acme.yourpackagename";
};
```