# Security errors on startup with Nashorn when deploying Spring application on server

Tags: java, spring, security, nashorn

I have a Spring Webapp that throws some confusing errors on startup when I deploy it to my production server (they don't happen when I run it locally)- the errors don't seem to impact anything, so this question is more out of curiosity than a true need for help.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
20-Apr-2016 17:31:31.711 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass Security Violation, attempt to use Restricted Class: jdk.internal.dynalink.support.messages_en_US
 java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.jdk.internal.dynalink.support")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1564)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1268)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2640)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1501)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1465)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1361)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1082)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.findResourceBundle(Logger.java:1879)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1940)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:380)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:554)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:553)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.Guards.<clinit>(Guards.java:101)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined.<clinit>(Undefined.java:51)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSType.<clinit>(JSType.java:263)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.AccessorProperty.<clinit>(AccessorProperty.java:60)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.$clinit$(Global.java)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:919)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.newGlobal(Context.java:1102)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$2.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:347)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$2.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:343)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.createNashornGlobal(NashornScriptEngine.java:343)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.<init>(NashornScriptEngine.java:143)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(NashornScriptEngineFactory.java:148)
    at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(ScriptEngineManager.java:238)
    at com.my.applicationlib.security.ScriptSandbox.<init>(ScriptSandbox.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$4.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1089)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ...
```

And the relevant code is as follows:

```
@Service
public class ScriptSandbox {
    ScriptEngine _scriptEngine;
    AccessControlContext _accessControlContext;

    public ScriptSandbox() throws InstantiationException{
        ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
        _scriptEngine = sem.getEngineByName("nashorn");//This error happens on this line.
        if (_scriptEngine==null){
            throw new InstantiationException("Could not load script engine: "+
                    "nashorn");
        }
        setPermissions(null);
   }
}
```

I haven't been able to turn up much relevant information on google, the most I've seen is that I need it in my java security configuration. Mine looks like this so I think I have what I need:

```
grant {permission java.security.AllPermission; permission java.lang.RuntimePermission;};
```

Any thoughts?

Edit: This question was marked as a duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917474/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission) I don't think it is for the following reasons:

it works just fine when I initialize nashorn later in the application it seems to work. I only get this error on bean definition from what I can tell. Don't think it's a signing issue as it only comes up on bean definition.

Furthermore, that question has no accepted answers and few votes. Are any of those actually solutions to this problem?

Comment: I have added some clarification which I hope differentiates this question from the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I got around this in a way I'm not *super* happy about. Since I only used this in one service, I removed the service annotation entirely, and call initialized it in a @PostConstruct method. I still want to know why this doesn't work during the bean creation phase of Spring.

```
@Service
public class MyServiceThatUsesScriptSandbox(){
    private ScriptSandbox sandbox;
    @PostConstruct
    public void initSandbox(){
        sandbox = new ScriptSandbox();
    }
}
```